# Exploding an array into 2 columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we want to track the hops made by an package from warehouse to the customer.
We have a table which store the data but the data is in a column SAY Route
The package starts at the Warehouse – YYY,TTT,MMM
The hops end when the package is delivered to the CUSTOMER
The values in the Route column are separated by space

```
ID  Route   
1   TTT A B X Y Z CUSTOMER
2   YYY E Y F G I P B X Q CUSTOMER
3   MMM R T K L CUSTOMER
```

Expected Output

```
ID START    END
1   TTT     A
1   A       B
1   B       X
.
.
.
1   Z       CUSTOMER
2   YYY     E
2   E       Y
2   Y       F
.
.
2   Q       CUSTOMER
3   MMM     R
.
.
3   L       CUSTOMER
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in pyspark

Comment: what's your spark version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index to the split route using `posexplode`, and get the location at the next index for each starting location using `lead`. If you want to remove the index simply add `.drop('index')` at the end.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.select(
    'ID',
    F.posexplode(F.split('Route', ' ')).alias('index', 'start')
).withColumn(
    'end', 
    F.lead('start').over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('index'))
).orderBy('ID', 'index').dropna()

df2.show(99,0)
+---+-----+-----+--------+
|ID |index|start|end     |
+---+-----+-----+--------+
|1  |0    |TTT  |A       |
|1  |1    |A    |B       |
|1  |2    |B    |X       |
|1  |3    |X    |Y       |
|1  |4    |Y    |Z       |
|1  |5    |Z    |CUSTOMER|
|2  |0    |YYY  |E       |
|2  |1    |E    |Y       |
|2  |2    |Y    |F       |
|2  |3    |F    |G       |
|2  |4    |G    |I       |
|2  |5    |I    |P       |
|2  |6    |P    |B       |
|2  |7    |B    |X       |
|2  |8    |X    |Q       |
|2  |9    |Q    |CUSTOMER|
|3  |0    |MMM  |R       |
|3  |1    |R    |T       |
|3  |2    |T    |K       |
|3  |3    |K    |L       |
|3  |4    |L    |CUSTOMER|
+---+-----+-----+--------+
```